# prebuilt agents import in dialog flow is not working

Tags: dialogflow-es

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3VNO.png)
in Dialog flow I am not able to import the prebuilt agents to my chatbot , its only saying preparing your agent templet but its not working. How can i solve this issue?
Its been 30minitues but it is only showing this type of message but I want to integrate the prebuilt agents to my chatbot so that i can improve my chatbot.
I want to import web search agent into my chat bot but its not importing it.

Comment: I couldn't either, but it's suddenly working now. Did you check it?